# Android анимация TRANSLATION_X выглядит по разному на разных экранах

Tags: android, анимация, координаты

Я использую следующий код, для анимации перемещения моей View, но конечная точка в которую приходит View после анимации, разная для разных устройств. Что я должен подать за место -400, чтобы анимация останавливалась в одной и той же точке на всех устройствах, не зависимо от экрана.

**Мой код анимации:**

```
   ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,View.TRANSLATION_X,-400);
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.play(objectAnimator);
        set.setDuration(550);
        set.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    final float moveLeftValue = 30f;
    final float moveRightValue = view.getLeft();

ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.X, moveRightValue, moveLeftValue);
```

Конечным решением для меня стало использование **view.getLeft()**, чтобы рассчитать начальную точку (для моей анимации), которая и менялась визуально относительно нулевой точки в зависимости от экрана. Получается что в метод **ofFloat()** для анимации **View.X** подаются координаты. Для каждого устройства координаты не меняются, а меняется область их видимости, по этому точка 0;0 будет видна всегда не зависимо от устройства.
А точка скажем 400;0 будет видна, только на некоторых устройствах. Поэтому её требуется считать динамически. Метод **getLeft()** как раз и возвращает значение, от нулевой точки до левого края квадрата view. Прибавляя к этому значению, можно получить точку, которая будет отображаться одинаково на всех экранах, но фактически в системе координат будет разная.
Так же может произойти такая ситуация, что **view.getLeft()** вернёт ноль. Например так происходит после **view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)**, если до этого view было **View.GONE**. Чтобы не получать ноль в первый раз, нужно чтобы view во время создания макета было **View.INVISIBLE**. Тогда **view.getLeft()** не возвращает ноль.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас вы перемещаете ваше `view` на 400 пикселей(px), но разрешение у устройств разное, поэтому и получаете что анимация у вас останавливается в разных точках.

Что бы на всех устройствах точка остановки находилась в одном и том же месте, вам нужно использовать dp(`Density-independent Pixels`), а уже их перевести в пиксели. Для перевода можете воспользоваться следующим методом:

```
public static int dpToPx(int dp) {
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

т.е. ваша задача сначала перевести ваше значение в px, а уже потом передать в метод `ofFloat()`.

Comment: Всё равно анимация останавливается в разных точках на эмуляторе и на физическом устройстве.

Comment: float startValue = dpToPx(170);
        float endValue = dpToPx(30);            
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(addGroupFAB, View.X, startValue, endValue);
Вот что я делаю.

Comment: тогда возникает вопрос по поводу того что вы подразумеваете под "в одной и той же точке на разных устройствах"

Comment: "В одной и той же точке на разных устройствах", я подразумеваю, то что анимация должна выглядеть одинаково на любых устройствах. То есть не зависимо от экрана перемещалась на одинаковое расстояние.